# Problema PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, servidor

Após uma queda de energia reiniciamos o servidor no qual está o banco de dados está localizado e apesar tentarmos levantar o banco manualmente o banco não levanta. A mensagem que ocorre é essa abaixo:

> FATAL: The database system is starting up.

Alguém pode dar um auxilio?

Não sei como, mas depois de um certo tempo o banco conseguiu levantar sozinho.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez se você parar todos os processos do postgres utilizando uma ferramenta como htop e depois tentar iniciar de novo com o comando "sudo service postgresql start"... vale a pena tentar.

Comment: Quem sabe em outra ocasião. O banco acabou de levantar sozinho, não que seja ruim, mas não é legal que coisas assim aconteçam sem uma causa aparente. De qualquer modo, obrigado pela dica ;)